# How can chaincode get the block height in Hyperledger Fabric 2.x?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

I'm coding in Hyperledger Fabric 2.4. I need to query the current block height in the chaincode but I didn't find such a function. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Chaincode can obtain information about the channel, using the [`system chaincode`](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/smartcontract/smartcontract.html?highlight=system#system-chaincode). The `system chaincode` is "built-in" when a blockchain network is up

channel information(with block height) can be obtained through the `QSCC` system chaincode.

> Query system chaincode (QSCC) runs in all peers to provide ledger APIs which include block query, transaction query etc

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim"
    pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer"
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    commonProto "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/common"
)

func (t *MyChaincode) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response {
    // ... your chaincode logic ...

    // Define the system chaincode you want to call and the arguments.
    // In this example, we'll query the block height using the "qscc" system chaincode.
    sysCC := "qscc"
    fcn := "GetChainInfo"
    channelID := "mychannel"

    // Call the system chaincode
    response := stub.InvokeChaincode(sysCC, [][]byte{[]byte(fcn), []byte(channelID)}, channelID)

    // Check the response for errors
    if response.Status != shim.OK {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("Error invoking '%s' chaincode: %s", sysCC, response.Message)
        return shim.Error(errMsg)
    }

    // Process the response payload
    result := response.Payload

    // Unmarshal the response payload
    chainInfo := &commonProto.BlockchainInfo{}
    err := proto.Unmarshal(result, chainInfo)
    if err != nil {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("Error unmarshaling BlockchainInfo: %s", err)
        return shim.Error(errMsg)
    }

    // Get the block height
    blockHeight := chainInfo.GetHeight()

    // ... do something with the block height

    // ... continue with your chaincode logic and return the appropriate response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! I always got 0.

Is the line correct, the channelID appeared twice.

`response := stub.InvokeChaincode(sysCC, [][]byte{[]byte(fcn), []byte(channelID)}, channelID)`

should it be

`response := stub.InvokeChaincode(sysCC, [][]byte{[]byte(fcn)}, channelID)`